# jQuery table replace partial table content inside html

Tags: jquery, html, replace, html-table, cell

I have this table:

**HTML**

```
<div class="BBclass1 BBclass2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>name:</b> value1</td>
            <td>Value2</td>
            <td>Value3</td>
            <td>Value4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<div>
```

I need to replace `'name:'` **to** `'Hello:'`

How do I do this?

I have already tried

```
$("td :contains('name:')").text("Hello:");
```

For some reason it replaces the entire table with name1.

this does not work either:

```
$("div:contains('name:')").html("Hello");
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `using the wrong selector.`

There should be no space between

```
`"td :contains"`
    ^------- Remove this space
```

Supposed to be

```
$("td:contains('name:')").text("Hello:");
```

You can also try

```
$("td b:contains('name:')").text("Hello:");
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/stYF4/)**

Comment: Glad to have helped :)